# How to create a custom Button instead of downward arrow for exporting in Material UI Table (like button with text Download)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I want to have a custom Button for downloading the data to excel.I am able to do that using developer tools but those changes cant be persisted permanently.can anyone provide a better solution?

Comment: Are you using `GridToolbarExport` from `DataGrid`?

Comment: No,i am using material ui table.